# Double pipe in front of URL - Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, http, url, adblock

Looking at [URL listings for adblockers](https://easylist.to/easylist/easylist.txt) and seeing entries with double pipes preceding the URL:

`||akamai.net^*.247realmedia.com/$third-party`

Anyone know what these double pipes refer to? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not the RegEx but how AdBlock scripts use it.

Quoting from https://adblockplus.org/en/filters, "Matching at beginning/end of an address" section

> Sometimes one wants to block `http://example.com/banner.gif` as well as `https://example.com/banner.gif` and `http://www.example.com/banner.gif`. This can be achieved by putting two pipe symbols in front of the filter which makes sure the filter matches at the beginning of the domain name: `||example.com/banner.gif` will block all these addresses while not blocking `http://badexample.com/banner.gif` or `http://gooddomain.example/analyze?http://example.com/banner.gif` (requires Adblock Plus 1.1 or higher).

From above, it's clear that two pipes `||` are used to match the beginning of domain.